# Javascript language switcher

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have another question about my code I have currently found a script that translates different `<p>` blocks. Now I have the following problem I would like to change the tag from French "fr" to German "de". I thought this would be very easy and I change everything from "fr" to "de" unfortunately the script doesn't work anymore. Can anyone help me ?

```
let langs = ['en', 'fr'];
let lang = 'en';
setLangStyles(lang);

function setStyles(styles) {
    var elementId = '__lang_styles';
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    if (element) {
        element.remove();
    }

    let style = document.createElement('style');
    style.id = elementId;
    style.type = 'text/css';

    if (style.styleSheet) {
        style.styleSheet.cssText = styles;
    } else {
        style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(styles));
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
}

function setLang(lang) {
    setLangStyles(lang);
}

function setLangStyles(lang) {
    let styles = langs
    .filter(function (l) {
        return l != lang;
    })
    .map(function (l) {
        return ':lang('+ l +') { display: none; }';
    })
    .join(' ');

    setStyles(styles);
}
```

My index.php

```
<a href="" hreflang="en" onclick="setLang('en'); return false">English</a>
<a href="" hreflang="fr" onclick="setLang('fr'); return false">Deutsch</a>
<p lang='en'>Hi everyone!</p>
<p lang='fr'>Guten Tag!</p>
```

The problem when I change all "fr" tags to English so "de" the Script doesn't work anymore ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's worrking for me, I have just added `#` to `href="#"`, and replaced all `fr` to `de`

```js
let langs = ['en', 'de']; //Changed
let lang = 'en';
setLangStyles(lang);

function setStyles(styles) {
  var elementId = '__lang_styles';
  var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
  if (element) {
    element.remove();
  }

  let style = document.createElement('style');
  style.id = elementId;
  style.type = 'text/css';

  if (style.styleSheet) {
    style.styleSheet.cssText = styles;
  } else {
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(styles));
  }
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
}

function setLang(lang) {
  debugger
  setLangStyles(lang);
}

function setLangStyles(lang) {
  let styles = langs
    .filter(function(l) {
      return l != lang;
    })
    .map(function(l) {
      return ':lang(' + l + ') { display: none; }';
    })
    .join(' ');

  setStyles(styles);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" hreflang="en" onclick="setLang('en'); return false">English</a>
<a href="#" hreflang="de" onclick="setLang('de'); return false">Deutsch</a> <!-- Changed -->
<p lang='en'>Hi everyone!</p>
<p lang='de'>Guten Tag!</p> <!-- Changed -->
```

Example with 3 languages.

```js
let langs = ['en', 'fr', 'de']; //Changed
let lang = 'en';
setLangStyles(lang);

function setStyles(styles) {
  var elementId = '__lang_styles';
  var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
  if (element) {
    element.remove();
  }

  let style = document.createElement('style');
  style.id = elementId;
  style.type = 'text/css';

  if (style.styleSheet) {
    style.styleSheet.cssText = styles;
  } else {
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(styles));
  }
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
}

function setLang(lang) {
  debugger
  setLangStyles(lang);
}

function setLangStyles(lang) {
  let styles = langs
    .filter(function(l) {
      return l != lang;
    })
    .map(function(l) {
      return ':lang(' + l + ') { display: none; }';
    })
    .join(' ');

  setStyles(styles);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" hreflang="en" onclick="setLang('en'); return false">English</a>
<a href="#" hreflang="fr" onclick="setLang('fr'); return false">French</a>
<a href="#" hreflang="de" onclick="setLang('de'); return false">Deutsch</a>
<p lang='en'>Hi everyone!</p>
<p lang='fr'>Salut à tous!</p>
<p lang='de'>Guten Tag!</p>
```